# Create a table with json columns

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to create a oracle table with json column but the following error is giving

```
 CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder
   (id          RAW (16) NOT NULL,
    date_loaded TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    po_document CLOB
    CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (po_document IS JSON));
```

I am using oracle 12c standard edition one

Comment: You need a comma after the column definition and before the constraint `... po_document clob , constraint ...`

Comment: Even with comma also not working, my doubt is this feature is available in oracle 12c standard edition one

Comment: JSON works with standard edition as well. But what is your **exact** Oracle version? JSON support was added in 12.2 - if you are still on 12.1 then this will not work.

Comment: thank u ours is 12.1

Answer (score 0):

it's working with Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

```
CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder
(
    id            RAW (16) NOT NULL,
    date_loaded   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    po_document   CLOB, 
    CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (po_document IS JSON));
```

see the screens

[image: Table]

[image: Constarint]

[Oracle Database 12c Release 2 12.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZl4m.png)

Comment: Its not working, my doubt is this feature is available in the oracle 12c standard edition one

Comment: Try with Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2)  "Oracle Database 12c Release 1(12.1) introduced a number of JSON conditions and functions available from SQL. Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2) now supports these conditions and functions in PL/SQL also".  https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr2